# Sending big strings over RPC is causing trouble

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

So this is a quick question.

I have now reached the stage of sending my image to the blobstore but the RPC part is causing issues.

Sending the base64 encoded image data(like this data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS etc) over RPC results in server-side a ?header? being added to the string.

So the string becomes

7|0|6|http://127.0.0.1:8888/justatest/|EEBD10CD0*more numbers*com.rohan.justatest.client.linkservice.getlink.java.lang.string/2010016611|data:image/png;base64rest of my image and at the end 1|2|3|4|5|6

So my question to you, why is this happening? i don't mind a technical story.

Or... is RPC not built for bigger files and should i use the RequestBuiler instead?

Also i tried a wrapper class with one string in it and it gave the same result.

Thanks in advance, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching a header of this size will cause issues to RPC, i suggest you use a HttpRequestBuilder.